# MySQL Display tables that have x amount of records

Tags: mysql, sql, information-schema

I am using 'show tables' to get the names of tables from MySQL.
I would like to know if its possible to have one query that would display only tables that have more than '100' records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,TABLE_ROWS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR DB NAME' AND
      TABLE_ROWS > 100
```